# logging from different classes with the same logger

Tags: logging, groovy

groovy

I've inherited an app that is broken up into several classes and one main script.
A logging configuration file exists somewhere but I do not have access to it.
All classes and the script declare loggers using

```
def logger = com.datacert.utils.Logger.getLogger( this.class.getName())
```

and make use of statements like

```
logger.log( Level.INFO, "TopScript - main - countAnimals - entering")
logger.log( Level.INFO, "Sheep - countSheep - entering")
logger.log( Level.INFO, "Sheep - countSheep - exiting")
logger.log( Level.INFO, "Dog - countBreedCollie - entering")
logger.log( Level.INFO, "Dog - countBreedCollie - exiting")
logger.log( Level.INFO, "Dog - countBreedSchnauzer - entering")
logger.log( Level.INFO, "Dog - countBreedSchnauzer - exiting")
```

Problem is only logging statements from the mail script appear in the log file

```
**TopScript - main - countAnimals - entering**
```

I've tried explicity naming the logger in each class to

```
    def logger = com.datacert.utils.Logger.getLogger( "TopLevel")
```

without success. In fact the only thing that has worked is removing every class logger definition and passing the "main" logger as an argument to every function call in every class

```
TopScript.groovy----------------------------
    def logger = com.datacert.utils.Logger.getLogger( this.class.getName())
    ...
    public void countAnimals() {
        sheep.countSheep( logger)
        dog.countBreedCollie( logger)
        dog.countBreedSchnauzer( logger)
    }
}
```

There has got to be a better way than this. How can a class get the logger in use by its parent class at runtime? Or better still the logger initiated by main() in any execution? For after all it's far more common that the methods in Employee will be called by many programs that all write to the same logfile .

Any ideas?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Comment: Does `this.class.getName()` for your "main script" class actually returns "TopLevel", or is it something like "com.organization.project.TopLevel"?

Comment: Not sure that'd make a difference but an excellent question, I'll have to check.

Comment: would it make sense to replace all loggers and calls with log4j-conformed ones, like `@Log4j` and `log.info "blah"`. Then you can properly configure it.

Comment: Can we assume, that `com.datacert.utils.Logger.getLogger` is a) not
share-able by you and that b) you _have to_ use it to make your scripts
log properly in the context they run?

Comment: On a second note, minor mistypings like `main` vs `mail` and `TopScript` vs `TopLevel` make it hard to no just blame those as problems.

Comment: answering cfrick - yes and yes.  The base code of this 3rd-party app cannot be touched, nay not even viewed (closed-hood, if you will) by leasees . We can only write custom code to extend functionality

Comment: 2nd answering cfrick - simplifications for SO. And Thank You  for replying!

Comment: What is the underlying logging framework here?  How does your code get access to that "main" logger?  It could be that the 3rd party is doing tricks to prevent you from creating more than 1 logger.